# Написал программу с Antlr 4. Сделал ярлык на рабочий стол

Tags: c#

Если открыть exe в папке проекта, то все отлично работает, но если на рабочем столе, то при вводе числа для вычисления выдает ошибку "couldn’t load assembly or file "Antlr4Runtime...".. Что это может быть?

Comment: Это может быть наверно установленная рабочая папка для вашего приложения.

Comment: вы хотели сказать "неверно"?

Comment: Да, хотел написать "неверно"